# Vardump() in php is confusing me

Tags: php

My friend and I are at programming camp, and we were messing around with some php. We both noticed something weird though, and we weren't able to figure out the reason for our error. For some reason, adding a parentheses changes the output of our vardump(). What is going on here?

```
var_dump((bool) (2==5)); //returns bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 2==5); //returns bool(true)
```

Comment: The second one you have shown, would throw a parse error.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am guessing the second one should be `var_dump((bool) 2==5);`

Comment: The first, you're casting (2==5) to a boolean. The second, you're casting 2 to a boolean, then comparing it to 5, which would evaluate to true since 5 is a non-zero number.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that would be my guess too...

Comment: Generally if adding parentheses changes the output you expected, you should examine [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). You can see there that cast has higher precedence than comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type casting applies to the first entity, or operand.

`(2==5)` since it's wrapped in parentheses is interpreted together.   So `2==5` is `false`, so `(bool) false` is still `false`.

The second is transforming `2` to a bool, which is `true` and a loose comparsion of `true` to `5` is also `true` since any integer other than 0 is evaluated loosely as true.

This comes down to:

```
2 == true
5 == true
```

Comment: Amazing question and explanation, never thought of getting into this approach ever.

Comment: @Dude156 no problem.  Loose comparisons with `==` are good when you don't know the type, but try to use strict comparisons with `===` when possible.